# Un-load compiled XSLT (xsltExecutable) from ehCache

Tags: java, xslt, ehcache, saxon

In my application, we have around 300 XSLT files which are stored in config folder. These XSLT's are required to transform input messages. In a day our application is expected to received 90K input files, and all of them need transformation.

That's why we want to store compiled XSLT's in cache to improve the transformation process. To do so, I have created a **net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable** object in java, and managed to store it in ehCache.

The issue is while retrieving this object back from cache, because xsltExecutable object cannot be serialized. And **cache.get("fileName")** returns ValueWrapper object which does not return xsltExecutable object anyway.

Please provide me as much suggestions are possible here...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler;
import net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable;

File transformerDirectory = new File("C:\\path\\transformer\\");

@Cacheable(value = "transformerCache", key = "#name")
private boolean loadCompiledTransformers(String fileName) throws Exception {

Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("transformerCache");
if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
    for (File file : transformerDirectory.listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().contains("xsl")) {
            cache.put(file.getName(), loadServiceTransforms(file));
        }
    }
} else {
    cache.put(fileName, loadServiceTransforms(new File(transformerDirectory+"\\"+fileName)));
}
return true;
}

private XsltExecutable loadServiceTransforms(File file) throws Exception {

XsltExecutable template = null;
StreamSource xslSource;

xslSource = new StreamSource(file);
try {
    XsltCompiler compiler = new Processor(true).newXsltCompiler();
    template = compiler.compile(xslSource);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
return template;
}
```

cache.xml looks as below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>

<service>
    <jsr107:defaults enable-statistics="true" />
</service>

<cache alias="serviceCache">
    <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
    <value-type>java.util.Properties</value-type>
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">20</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <resources>
        <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
        <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap>
    </resources>
</cache>

<cache alias="transformerCache">
    <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
    <value-type>net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable</value-type>
    <expiry>
        <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
    <resources>
        <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
        <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap>
    </resources>
</cache>
```

Transforms are compiled successfully, but below stack trace while applying caching:

```
ERROR 27600 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class net.sf.saxon.serialize.charcode.CharacterSetFactory]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class net.sf.saxon.serialize.charcode.CharacterSetFactory and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable["processor"]->net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor["schemaManager"]->com.saxonica.ee.s9api.SchemaManagerImpl["schemaURIResolver"]->com.saxonica.config.ee.StandardSchemaResolver["configuration"]->com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfiguration["characterSetFactory"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class net.sf.saxon.serialize.charcode.CharacterSetFactory and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltExecutable["processor"]->net.sf.saxon.s9api.Processor["schemaManager"]->com.saxonica.ee.s9api.SchemaManagerImpl["schemaURIResolver"]->com.saxonica.config.ee.StandardSchemaResolver["configuration"]->com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseConfiguration["characterSetFactory"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:403) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:721) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1433) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:921) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:295) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you are doing and exactly how it is failing. (Having said that, I have no knowledge of ehCache and after a quick glance at the documentation I have very little idea why I would want to use it.)

Comment: More updated provided over the port, please could you refer above and let me know if you need more details

Comment: Thanks, the additional information shows that you're using a technology stack that I know very little about.

Answer (score 0):

you could provide the compiled stylesheet as a spring bean instead

```
@Configuration
public class XsltConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("XslA")
    XsltExecutable getXsltExecutableA() {
        XsltCompiler compiler = new Processor(true).newXsltCompiler();
        //load xsl ...
        return compiler.compile(xslSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("XslB")
    XsltExecutable getXsltExecutableB() {
        XsltCompiler compiler = new   Processor(true).newXsltCompiler();
        //load xsl ...
        return compiler.compile(xslSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc, we have around 300 xslt's and 90K input files received a day. Do I need to create 300 getXsltExecutableXXX methods as spring bean??   There are 5 java api's (running in docker containers) which would be trying to transform input files. That's why we need to make these compiled transforms available in cache so that all API's can access it.

Comment: create an XsltManager-Bean which holds all your XsltExecutables in a Map and inject this bean. So you don't need the getxxx - Methods. XsltExecutable would be cached once per container.